# Find the value of $\theta$ and $x$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the value of $x$ and $\theta$ if

$$2 \sin(\theta + x) = 1\;\text{and}\;2\cos(\theta -x) = 1.$$

Comment: Expand and solve for $\sin x,\cos x$ in terms of $\theta$

Answer (score 1):

For $\sin(\theta+x)=\frac 12$, we obtain $$\theta+x=\frac{\pi}6+2\pi k \\ \theta+x=\frac{5\pi}6+2\pi k$$ for all integers $k$.

For $\cos(\theta-x)=\frac 12$, we obtain $$\theta - x=\frac{\pi}3+2\pi k \\ \theta - x=\frac{4\pi}3+2\pi k$$ for all integers $k$.

Try to system solve for $x$ and $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\sin\left(\theta+x\right)=\dfrac12=\sin\dfrac\pi6\implies\theta+x=n\pi+(-1)^n\dfrac\pi6\ \ \ \ (1)$ where $n$ is any integer

and

$\displaystyle\cos\left(\theta-x\right)=\dfrac12=\cos\dfrac\pi3\implies\theta-x=2m\pi\pm\dfrac\pi3\  \ \ \ (2)$ where $m$ is any integer

Solve $(1),(2)$ for $\theta,x$

Comment: It looks like you meant $\cos(\theta - x) = \frac{1}{2} = \cos \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, Hope the typo has been rectified

Answer (score 0):

the first one says $$\theta + x = \{\pi/6, 5\pi /6\} +2k\pi \tag 1 $$ the second one says $$\theta - x = \{\pi/3, 5\pi/3\} + 2m\pi \tag 2$$ you can solve these linear equations for $\theta$ and $x.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$2\cos \theta \sin x+2\sin \theta \cos x=1$$ and $$2\cos x \cos \theta+2\sin x \sin \theta =1$$

Multiply the first by $\cos x$ and the second by $\sin x$ and subtract $$2\sin \theta\cos^2 x-2\sin \theta \sin^2 x=\cos x-\sin x$$

Now either $\sin x=\cos x$ or $$2\sin\theta \cos x+2\sin \theta \sin x=1$$

Subtract this from the first equation $$2\cos\theta\sin x-2\sin \theta\sin x=0$$

And from this either $\sin \theta = \cos \theta$ or $\sin x =0$

Now if $\sin x =0$ it follows from the first two equations that $\sin \theta=\cos \theta$

Now it simply remains to analyse the two cases $\sin x= \cos x$ and $\sin \theta = \cos \theta$ noting that in either case the common value is $\pm\cfrac {\sqrt 2}2$, and the remaining equations involve only a single unknown angle.